# Redundant distributed NFS file system and replication factor > 1. Is it safe for Kafka deployment?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a cluster Kafka set up where the log.dir is set to a mounted NFS path pointing to distributed file system which all the brokers have access to.

Since the distributed file system provides all the redundancy I need, is it really necessary have a replication factor > 1?

Also, I read in this article https://engineering.skybettingandgaming.com/2018/07/10/kafka-nfs/ that you are not recommended to have the logs on an NFS mounted filesystem. Does this still hold and does anyone have any more experience in doing this?

Comment: So, basically you're emulating Pulsar's concept of decoupling the storage from the broker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the storage side, maybe this is safe, but your single replica is only able to be read / sent from a single broker.

If that machine goes down, the data will still be available on your backend, sure, but you cannot serve requests for it without knowing there is another replica for that topic (replication factor < 2).